# Reactjs Redirect to protected page after login not working after Authenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The router is not able to redirect to the protected page after login. I have built a login page that has `/login` and after login is supposed to redirect to `/dashboard` instead it stays there what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is the gist of my code or this my github [link](https://github.com/anishnath/palkadot-scanner/blob/main/src/App.js) for complete code

Login page code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {
  CButton,
  CCard,
  CCardBody,
  CCardGroup,
  CCol,
  CContainer,
  CForm,
  CFormFeedback,
  CFormInput,
  CInputGroup,
  CInputGroupText,
  CRow,
} from '@coreui/react'
import CIcon from '@coreui/icons-react'
import { cilLockLocked, cilUser } from '@coreui/icons'
import axios from 'axios'
import qs from 'qs'
import Auth from '../../../Auth/Auth'

const Login = () => {
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setError(null)
    switch (name) {
      case 'username':
        setUsername(e.target.value)
        break
      case 'password':
        setPassword(e.target.value)
        break
    }
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const bodyFormData = new FormData()
    const form = event.currentTarget
    Auth.authenticate()
    setError(null)
    setValidated(true)
  }
  return (
    <div className="bg-light min-vh-100 d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
      <CContainer>
        <CRow className="justify-content-center">
          <CCol md={8}>
            <CCardGroup>
              <CCard className="p-4">
                <CCardBody>
                  <CForm
                    className="row g-3 needs-validation"
                    noValidate
                    validated={validated}
                    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                  >
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <p className="text-medium-emphasis">Sign In to your account</p>
                    <CInputGroup className="mb-3">
                      <CInputGroupText>
                        <CIcon icon={cilUser} />
                      </CInputGroupText>
                      <CFormInput
                        id="username"
                        name="username"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        autoComplete="username"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        required
                      />
                      <CFormFeedback invalid>Please input Username</CFormFeedback>
                    </CInputGroup>
                    <CInputGroup className="mb-4">
                      <CInputGroupText>
                        <CIcon icon={cilLockLocked} />
                      </CInputGroupText>
                      <CFormInput
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        required
                      />
                      <CFormFeedback invalid>Please input password</CFormFeedback>
                    </CInputGroup>
                    <CRow>
                      <CCol xs={6}>
                        <CButton color="primary" type="submit" className="px-4">
                          Login
                        </CButton>
                        {error}
                      </CCol>
                    </CRow>
                    {/*<CRow>*/}
                    {/*  <CCol xs={6}>{error}</CCol>*/}
                    {/*</CRow>*/}
                  </CForm>
                </CCardBody>
              </CCard>
            </CCardGroup>
          </CCol>
        </CRow>
      </CContainer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

The Auth.js file

```
const Auth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate() {
    this.isAuthenticated = true
  },
  signout() {
    this.isAuthenticated = false
  },
  getAuth() {
    return this.isAuthenticated
  },
}

export default Auth
```

App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { HashRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import './scss/style.scss'
import Dashboard from './views/dashboard/Dashboard'
import Auth from './Auth/Auth'

const loading = (
  <div className="pt-3 text-center">
    <div className="sk-spinner sk-spinner-pulse"></div>
  </div>
)

// Containers
const DefaultLayout = React.lazy(() => import('./layout/DefaultLayout'))

// Pages
const Login = React.lazy(() => import('./views/pages/login/Login'))

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) =>
      Auth.getAuth() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/',
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
)

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <React.Suspense fallback={loading}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={(props) => <Login {...props} />} />
            {/*<Route path="/" name="Home" render={(props) => <DefaultLayout {...props} />} />*/}
            <Route exact path="/" name="Login Page" render={(props) => <Login {...props} />} />
            <PrivateRoute
              path="/dashboard"
              name="Dashboard Page"
              render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </React.Suspense>
      </HashRouter>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: Just glanced at this, but it seems to me that since you are not doing a state or prop change, React will never know of the changes done to Auth.

Comment: Agreed. The `Auth` object isn't stored in any React component's state so updates to it won't trigger rerenders. Also, generally your private route component should redirect to login, and the login page should then redirect back to the route user was originally accessing. Your code seems to just bounce them to home page, and if they manage to navigate themselves to the login route it doesn't redirect them anywhere after they authenticate. Check the [auth workflow](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) demo.

Answer (score 1):

I have this implemented in a slightly different way, and it works so I'm going to share it, maybe it helps :

This is similar to your `PrivateRoute`:

```
const ProtectedRoute = (props) => {
  const { state } = useOvermind();

  return (
    <Route {...props}>
      {state.user.isLoggedIn === true && props.children}
      {state.user.isLoggedIn !== true && <Redirect to="/login" />}
    </Route>
  );
};
```

Then on the App.js I have :

```
(...)
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />
    <Route path="/">
      <ProtectedRoute exact={true} path="/">
        <DashboardScreen />
      </ProtectedRoute>
      {state.user.isAdmin && (
        <ProtectedRoute path="/users">
          <UsersScreen />
        </ProtectedRoute>
      )}
      <ProtectedRoute path="/suppliers">
        <SuppliersScreen />
      </ProtectedRoute>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
(...)
```

And on the Login screen I have :

```
const LoginScreen = (props) => {
  const { state } = useOvermind();

  return (
    <>
      {state.user.isLoggedIn && <Redirect to="/" />}
      {!state.user.isLoggedIn && (
        (... rest of code here...)
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Like Chris just mentioned on the comments, you need to update your state in order for the code to work. In my case I'm using Overmind for state management, and I update `user.isLoggedIn` (which starts as `false`) to `true`, after a successful Login api call.

Also on the App.js I'm just showing the code inside the render function, specifically related to the `Router`.

On App.js I also use another boolean (`state.user.isAdmin`) to only show a link to the users screen, if the user is an Administrator. Of course, inside of the `Users` screen I also have a verification, similar to the one on the `Login` screen, which verifies if `state.user.isAdmin===true` to allow rendering the screen, otherwise it redirects again to the main screen (`<Redirect to="/" />`).